# python - Why is this code giving an "PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed" error?

Tags: python

I can't seem to find a way to fix this problem.

```
from scapy.all import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Lock

pkts = []    
lock = Lock()

def MyPrint(que):
    count = 0
    while 1:
        if que.qsize() == 0 :
            continue
        pkts.append(que.get())
        print '%d packet' % count
        print pkts[count].sprintf("Source:{IP:%IP.src%}:{TCP:%TCP.sport%} ===> Dest:{IP:%IP.dst%}:{TCP:%TCP.dport%}\n: {Raw:%Raw.load%}\n\n")
        count = count + 1

def CollectPacket(x, que):
    lock.acquire()
    que.put(x)
    lock.release()

def MySniffing(que):
    sniff(filter='ip host 172.20.64.12', prn=lambda x: CollectPacket(x, que))

def main():
    que = Queue()
    pr1 = Process(target=MySniffing, args=(que, ))
    pr2 = Process(target=MyPrint, args=(que,))

    pr1.start()
    pr2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This produces the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 264, in _feed
    send(obj)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Comment: Did the traceback have more lines than that?

Comment: As an aside, `multiprocessing.Queue` is thread safe. You don't need the extra lock.

Comment: ...and `Queue.get` blocks til data is available. `if que.qsize() == 0 :` just burns cpu cycles and queue size is documented as not reliable.